# Does an identifier declared with external linkage w/o external definition and used in _Generic violate semantics?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

From the latest [C2x](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf) (6.9p5) (emphasis added):

> An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an
> inline definition) or an object. If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression
> (other than as part of the operand of a typeof operator whose result is not a variably modified type,
> or a sizeof or alignof operator whose result is an integer constant expression), *somewhere in the
> entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier*; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

Consider this program:

```
extern int x;
int i = _Generic(x, default: 0);
int main(void)
{
}
```

As I understand per the quote above somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier `x`. Is that correct? FYI: [popular compilers don't complain](https://godbolt.org/z/PbYY8jPdh).

Perhaps 6.9p5 misses `_Generic`?

---

I'm also confused with "otherwise, there shall be no more than one". Hence, extra questions:

1. What "otherwise ..." is related to? To "somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier" OR to "an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than ...)"?
2. If "otherwise ..." is related to "somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier", then I interpret the whole quote (6.9p5) as `ext_def_cnt == 1 || ext_def_cnt <= 1`, which is redundant (because it can be folded to `ext_def_cnt <= 1`). Can someone comment on that?

Comment: _What "otherwise ..." is related to?_ If it is not used in any expression

Comment: pmor, Rather than for a proposed spec C2X, consider the current one.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm pretty sure he's referring to that last sentence he cited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Generic` was added to the C standard years after the language about requiring a definition was already established, and failing to add an exception about it to 6.9 5 was an oversight.

Clearly the intent of 6.9 5 is that if a program needs a definition for an object or function, because the object or function is actually used, then there must be a definition. But if the identifier is used in a context where only its type is needed, not the object or function it hypothetically refers to, then no definition is needed.

> I'm also confused with "otherwise, there shall be no more than one".

If an object or function is used, there needs to be a definition. This is a logical necessity: There is no way to use a thing that does not exist.

If an object or function is declared but not used, there does not need to be a definition. This allows slack in designing headers or source code generally: You can declare things that might or might not be linked into a program and used, and it will not be an error if they are declared but never used or defined.

Comment: _`_Generic` was added to the C standard years after the language about requiring a definition was already established_ But `typeof` is newer than `_Generic`, hm

Answer (score -1):

> Perhaps 6.9p5 misses `_Generic`?

No, *"If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (**other than as part of the operand of a `typeof` operator whose result is not a variably modified type**, or a `sizeof` or `alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant expression), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be **no more than one**"* - so, no external definition is required if used as an operand of a `typeof` operator.

From `6.5.1.1 Generic selection`:

- 3 **The controlling expression of a generic selection is not evaluated**. If a generic selection has a generic
  association with a type name that is compatible with the **type of the controlling expression**, then the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in that generic association. Otherwise, the
  result expression of the generic selection is the expression in the default generic association.

The variable `x`'s *type*, `int`, is known and that's all that is used in order to make the correct generic association. `x`, being the controlling expression, is never actually evaluated.

If anything is missing, it is in the `typeof` and/or `_Generic` chapters failing to mention that `_Generic` acts *as-if* using a `typeof` operator (unevaluated).

Comment: How does your answer explain why it is not missing?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I updated it to show more clearly why I don't see that it's missing from **6.9p5**. Even if you don't agree with my conclusion, do you think it's possible to follow my reasoning now?

Comment: Interesting reasoning. Do you consider "_everything_ that determines type of an expression" to act _as-if_ using a `typeof` operator?

Comment: @pmor No, it must be in an unevaluated context, like in `_Generic`'s controlling expression.

Comment: Do you consider "everything that determines type of an expression _in an unevaluated context_" to act _as-if_ using a `typeof` operator?

Comment: @pmor Yes, I think I do, unless already explicitly named, like `sizeof <expression>` which also determines the type of the expression without evaluating the expression. It feels like I'm walking into a trap :-) What do you have in mind?

Comment: If "everything that determines type of an expression in an unevaluated context" acts _as-if_ using a `typeof` operator, then such "everything" depends on constraints and semantics of `typeof` operator. I don't know whether such constraints and semantics will be satisfied _in all cases_. Exercise: do you see any case(s) when such constraints or semantics will not be satisfied? (In other words: can `typeof` operator _act as a drop-in replacement_ for "everything that determines type of an expression in an unevaluated context"?)

Comment: @pmor _"do you see any case(s) when such constraints or semantics will not be satisfied?"_ - No, I can't think of anything from the top of my head. It would be good to have one place in the standard really defining it and then all other places where it's used could refer to that chapter/paragraph/definition. The part _"(other than as part of the operand of a `typeof` operator whose result is not a variably modified type, or a `sizeof` or `alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant expression)"_ could then refer to that collective definition instead of the three separate definitions.

Comment: At least to me, merging _"the operand of a `typeof` operator whose result is not a variably modified type"_ and  _"the type of an unevaluated expression"_ sounds possible. That section could then be used for places where `sizeof <expression>` and `alignof` are mentioned too. What I do believe is that by listing _"other than as part of the operand of a `typeof` operator whose result is not a variably modified type"_,, the intent is to include the controlling expression in `_Generic`.